# Parsing words into (root, suffix) in AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I have a comma-separated csv file that contains a list of adjectives. I need to extract the root and suffix of each. Is it possible to do this with AWK?

Input file:

```
ypperlig;ypperlig;adj.;1
ypperlig;ypperlige;adj.;2
ypperlig;ypperligt;adj.;3
ypperlig;ypperligst;adj.;5
vunden;vunden;adj.;1
vunden;vundne;adj.;2
vunden;vundent;adj.;3
vunden;vundnest;adj.;5
```

Desired output file:

```
ypperlig,ypperlig,adj., ,e,t,*,st
vunden,vund,adj., ,ne,ent,*,nest
```

If a sequence number is missing in the column 4, like in these two examples, the space must be replaced by an asterisk.

hek2mgl Code:

```
BEGIN{
FS=";"
}

{
split($1,a,"")
split($2,b,"")

s=""
for(i in a)
{ 
    if(b[i]!=a[i])
    {
        break;
    }
    s = s "" a[i]
}

    stem[$1]=s;
    type[$1] = $3
}

{
    suf[$1] = suf[$1] "," substr($2,length(stem[$1])+1)
}


END {
for(i in stem) 
{
    printf "%s,%s, %s\n",i,stem[i],type[i],suf[i]
}   
}
```

output:

```
ypperlig,ypperlig,adj.,,e,t,st
vunden,vund,adj.,,ne,t,nest => wrong

ypperlig,ypperlig,adj., ,e,t,st    
vunden,vund,adj., ,ne,ent,nest
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible yes, but it requires a more complex awk program:

*script.awk*:

```
BEGIN{
    FS=","
}

# Get the stem and type through comparison between $1 and $2
!stem[$1]{
    split($1,a,"")
    split($2,b,"")

    s=""
    for(i in a){ 
        if(b[i]!=a[i]) {
            break;
        }
        s = s "" a[i]
    }   

    stem[$1] = s 
    type[$1] = $3
}

# Get suffix from $2
{
    suf[$1] = suf[$1] "," substr($2,length(stem[$1]) + 1)
}

# Print 
END {
    for(i in stem) {
        printf "%s,%s,%s, %s\n",i,stem[i],type[i],suf[i]
    }   
}
```

Call it:

```
awk -f script.awk input.file
```

Note: `awk` will mess up the input sort order. If you care about that, you might pipe the output to sort:

```
awk -f script.awk input.file | sort
```

Comment: Presumably the "stem" is the part which is invariant between all forms of an adjective. That's not necessarily the longest common suffix in the first instance, although it works in the two examples provided. If this is just Spanish and the file is sorted so that the second column is guaranteed to be in alphabetic order within common entries, then that assumption might work. But if the order is grammatical, then it will fail with adjectives like "veloz" (gender-invariant, plural "veloces"). It might also have trouble with words whose accent marker differs in the plural. (afín, afines)

Comment: @rici It was in fact Spanish. I didn't have the original file when I asked the question. The file is in Danish. What code would you propose?

Comment: @rici Yes, you are right. *stem* is not the right term here. I was only trying to solve the problem as described in the question. I don't master Spanish, but can say that in German it would also not work because of irregularities.

Comment: @hek2mlg The output of your script is not entirely correct. "vunden,vund,adj., ,,ne,t,nest"  The right thing is "vunden,vund,adj., ,,ne,ent,nest"

Comment: @hek2mgl: yes,I should have been clearer, but the problem is visible with the edit. You cache the stem the first time you see a word, but the real common prefix might turn out to be shorter. You need to collect all variants to correctly identify the longest common prefix.

Comment: Ah ok, will have a look at it if there is time. Btw, nice to see that the OP changed the question completely rendering my answer more or less wrong! ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl Sorry!! I didn't have the original file when I asked the question.Can you fix it?